# What is a good measure of "controversy", given a support score and opposition score?

Tags: statistics, scoring-algorithm

Suppose I have a topic or discussion, and a number of "support" and "opposition" points on each side (You can also think of them as "upvotes" and "downvotes") and I want to calculate a score of how "controversial" a topic is. (Let $p$ be the support score, $c$ be the opposition score, and $f(p, c)$ be the function that determines the controversy score.)

It should have the following properties:

- Controversy is maximized when equal support is given to both sides. Given that some property $g(p, c)$ is held constant (such that the slope of the tangent line of the level curve of $g(p, c)$ at any point is never positive), $f(p, c)$ should be maximized when $p = c$.
- More support on both sides means that more people care and therefore there is more controversy. Given that $p/c$ is held constant, a higher value of $p$ or $c$ should result in a higher value of $f(p, c)$.
- The amount of controversy is the same for the same imbalance of support no matter which side the imbalance favours. $f(p, c)$ should equal $f(c, p)$.
- All the support being on one side means there is no controversy. Given that either $p$ or $c$ is equal to zero, $f(p, c)$ should be equal to zero.

Is there any function like this that is already in use? If not, could one be devised?

Comment: Basically I'm trying to simulate or find a better formula for Reddit's "controversial" section. That section doesn't even seem to work properly on most subreddits I visit.

Comment: Selecting it on All made me realize that Controversial takes pretty much anything whose score is between 1 and -1 with more than 4 votes total.

Comment: Here's a [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/293649/how-to-rank-stories-based-on-controversy) on Stack Overflow that asks the same thing. But I'm interested in it mathematically as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$f = \min$$

---

More generally, choose an even function $g:[-1,1]\to\mathbb R_{\ge0}$ such that $g(-1)=g(1)=0$, and an increasing function $h:\mathbb R_{\ge0}\to\mathbb R_{\ge0}$, and let $$f(p,c)=g\left(\frac{p-c}{p+c}\right)h\left(\frac{p+c}2\right).$$ Here $g$ controls the "cross-section" for a fixed number of votes, while $h$ controls the growth for a fixed $p/c$ ratio. For example, $f(p,c)=\min(p,c)$ arises from setting $g(x)=1-\lvert x\rvert$ and $h(y)=y$. @michielm's solution $f(p,c)=pc/\lvert p-c\rvert$ corresponds to $g(x)=(1-x^2)/\lvert x\rvert$, $h(y)=y/2$. Another nice solution is $g(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}, h(y)=y \implies f(p,c)=\sqrt{pc}$.

Comment: I don't quite understand `f = min` at the top here. If we had one item, support 100, against 100 - fairly controversial, and we used min(), it would be scored 100 controversy. A second item, support 1000 against 101, would be scored 101 controversy. This wouldn't be correct: the first item is clearly more controversial. Does `f = min` mean something other than 'you can use min() for this`? Sorry if there's some kind of blazing ignorance here, I'm a programmer rather than a maths person.

Comment: @mikemaccana The proposed function takes into account how many people in total care about the issue, which seems reasonable to me. In your example, the face that the second item is 5.5 times as popular as the first arguably justifies the high score.

Answer (score 1):

What about $\frac{p c}{|p-c|}$?

This will grow (to infinity) for $c$ and $p$ being closer together and will also grow if $p/c=constant$ with increased $p c$. All support on one side will mean that $pc$ is low (or 0)

Maybe it is not perfect in its general behaviour, but the limiting behaviour seems to be right, so you can probably go from here.

Comment: I'm not sure 1 upvote vs. 1 downvote resulting in the same amount as 100 vs. 100 (both of which are "infinite") is a good idea. But thanks anyway.

Comment: A little adjustment like $\frac{pc}{|p-c|+1}$ would avoid infinity.

Answer (score 1):

The formula I came up with myself was: $\displaystyle \frac{\min(p,c)^2}{\max(p, c)}$

I called it the "geometric progression" algorithm, because it represents the next term of the geometric progression lower than $\max(p,c)$ and $\min(p, c)$. In this way, as $p$ increases past $c$, $f(p, c)$ will get smaller, reaching its maximum of $c$ when $p = c$.

It also has the additional scaling property that the number of votes on $\max(p,c)$ varies inversely with $f(p, c)$.

Comment: I created [a page](http://joezeng.com/code/upvotedownvote/upvote_downvote.html) where you can play with various upvote and downvote algorithms, with this formula on it.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that a simple and natural measure of controversy is simply the product of the support vote count $p$ and the opposed vote count $c$:

$$f(p,c) = pc$$

In particular, for a fixed total number of votes $p+c$, $f$ is maximized at $p = c$ (or at $p = c \pm 1$ if the total is odd), and it also satisfies your requirements 2–4.  It also has the convenient property that $f(p,c)$ is a non-negative integer whenever $p$ and $c$ are.

One downside is that, for a fixed vote ratio $0 < p/c < \infty$, $f(p,c)$ grows proportionally to the square of the total number of votes $p+c$.  If you'd prefer a linearly growing function instead, you can always take the square root to get the geometric mean of $p$ and $c$:

$$f^*(p,c) = \sqrt{pc}$$

As the square root is a strictly monotone increasing function, it does not affect the relative ranking of the results: $f(p,c) > f(p',c')$ if and only if $f^*(p,c) > f^*(p',c')$.  However, by the [AM–GM inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means), we can see that $f^*(p,c)$ can never exceed half of the total vote count $p+c$.

Comment: One problem with using $pc$ is that there are certain $g(p, c)$ for which the maximum value *isn't* at $p = c$. Originally I wanted to use $\displaystyle \frac{2pc}{p+c}$, but then I realized that if either $p$ or $c$ is constant, $f(p, c)$ actually *grows* when $p$ increases past $c$ or vice versa.

Comment: @Joe: Indeed, your full criterion 1 as stated is quite hard to satisfy. In particular, considering the "worst-case" test function $g(p,c)=\min(p,c)$ shows that no function $f(p,c)$ that satisfies both criteria 1 and 2 can be differentiable at points where $p=c$.

Comment: I had a hunch that was the case. The function I've come up with now is not differentiable on $p = c$ either.